# MailApp.sendEmail does not work: Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

this is meant to check the expiration dates of the documents and send an email to myself AND the user whose document has to be renewed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYxtP.png)

Why does the second MailApp.sendEmail (line 52) not work? The log shows "Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient". The weird thing is that the other one (line 51) works like a charm. Can anyone Help me?

```
function sendEmails(){
  // Recuperiamo il foglio di calcolo attivo
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var emailAddress = "nomm123@gmail.it"; 

  var subject = "Documento in scadenza";

  // Definiamo la riga iniziale come la seconda riga
  var startRow = 10; 
  
  // Calcoliamo il numero di righe presenti nel foglio
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 3;
  
  // Recuperiamo la gamma di dati compresa tra la riga iniziale e il numero di righe calcolato
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11)
  
  // Recuperiamo i valori da quella gamma di dati
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  /*var emaill = data[0];
  var email2 = emaill[0,10]
  Logger.log(email2);*/
    
  //Iteriamo attraverso i valori per inviare l'e-mail a ciascun indirizzo presente nella colonna A
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
    var row = data[i];

    var nome = row[i,0];

    var cognome = row[i,1];

    var doc = row[i,2];

    var mailPers = row[i,10];
    Logger.log(mailPers);

    var scadenza = new Date(row[i,4]);

    var alert = new Date(row[i,4]);

    alert.setDate(alert.getDate() - 30);

    var oggi = new Date();

    if (alert <= oggi){
      var message = "Attenzione:  " + doc + "  di  " + cognome + "  " + nome + "  scade il  " + scadenza;
      var userMessage = "Attenzione: il tuo documento  " + doc + "  scadrà in data  " + scadenza;
      Logger.log(message)

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailPers, subject, userMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you assign `row = data[i]` you do not need to use `i` any more, `row` is already a one-dimensional array. `Logger.log(mailPers);` should output `undefined`.

You need to replace all references like `row[i,10]` with `row[10]` (assuming that the integer index is correct).